# Eingenvalues: Regular, interesting sufficient condition question

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have come across a neat sufficient condition on eigenvalues to prove that they have equal algebraic and geometric multiplicity. I cannot really understand the reason why it works, tho. I was hoping you could give me some hints, or even better the full proof - I have looked into it quite a bit now.

The statement is as it follows:
$$
\ker(A-\lambda I)=\ker((A-\lambda I)^2) \qquad \implies \qquad a_\lambda=g_\lambda
$$
Where the geometric multiplicity follows immediately from the known inequality.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is not correct, pick $A=I_n$. We have that $\lambda=1$ has algebraic and geometric multiplicity $n$. Yet, $\mathrm{ker}(A-\lambda I)=\mathrm{ker}((A-\lambda I)^2)=\mathrm{ker}(0)=\mathbb{R}^n$. Your statement only say that the algebraic and geometric multiplicities are equal, but not that they are equal to one.

Comment: In that case the condition is even more useful. How do you prove that $a=g$, though?

Comment: This is merely a consequence of the definition. Assume that $a_\lambda=g_\lambda$, and that and let $v$ be an eigenvector of $\lambda$. Then, we have that $(A-\lambda I)v=0$. Since $a_\lambda\ne g_\lambda$, one can find a $w$ that verifies $(A-\lambda I)w=v$. Hence, we have that $(A-\lambda I)^2w=(A-\lambda I)v=0$, which means that $

Comment: It was trivial, you are right. thank for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition states that the algebraic multiplicity is equal to the geometric one, but they are necessarily equal to one.

To prove this, we consider the contrapositive and assume that $a_\lambda\ne g_\lambda$ and let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$ associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then, we have that $(A-\lambda I)v=0$. Since $a_\lambda\ne g_\lambda$, one can find a $w$ that verifies $(A-\lambda I)w=v\ne0$. Hence, we have that $(A-\lambda I)^2w=(A-\lambda I)v=0$, which implies that $\mathrm{ker}(A-\lambda I)\ne\mathrm{ker}((A-\lambda I)^2)$.